# Counting iterations in Newton-Raphson's method

Tags: c++, count, newtons-method

I'm working in a simple program that calculates the root of any given function using Newton-Raphson's method. In this program I have to print the found root and the number of iterations made. The program itself is fine, I can find the root of any given function but I can't count properly the number of iterations. It is always 5 over the max. number of iterations or 1 less than it. Here's the code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

double f(float x)
{
  double function1;
  function1 = exp(x)- 4*pow(x,2); // given function
  return function1;
}

double derivative(float x)
{
  double derivative1;
  derivative1 = exp(x) - 8*x; // derivative of given function
  return derivative1;
}


void newtonMethod(double x0, double error, int N)
{
  double xNext, xPrevious, root;
  int k;

  xPrevious = x0;

  for(int i = 0; i < N || f(xNext) > error; i++)
  {
    xNext = xPrevious - (f(xPrevious)/derivative(xPrevious)); // calculates the next value of x
    xPrevious = xNext;
    root = xNext;
    k = i;
}
cout << endl;
cout << "Iterations made: " << k << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Root is:  " << root << endl;


}

int main()
{
  double x0, error;
  int N; // max. number of iterations you can do
  cout << "Enter x0: ";
  cin >> x0;
  cout << "Enter the error: ";
  cin >> error;
  cout << "Enter the max. number of iterations: ";
  cin >> N;
  newtonMethod(x0, error, N);
 }
```

And I'm pretty sure the error is in this piece of code:

```
;i < N || f(xNext) > error;
```

If I run this program and put N = 100, it shows the right root but it prints "Iterations made = 99" but this is wrong. What do I do to print the right number of iterations made? For example, for the function in the program above (e^x - 4x²) it should stop in the fourth iteration if I enter x0 = 0.5 and error = 0.0001. How to fix it?

Comment: The computer works in binary, not decimal.  `0.0001` cannot be represented exactly in binary, thus you may / will not get the exact answer. -- *for the function in the program above (e^x - 4x²) it should stop in the fourth iteration if i enter x0 = 0.5 and error = 0.0001.* -- In your math book, yes, on a binary computing machine, maybe, maybe not.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but code like this `double f(float x) { double function1; function1 = exp(x)- 4*pow(x,2); return function1; }` is far too verbose. `double f(floats x) { return exp(x) - 4 * pow(x, 2); }` does the same thing and is much easier to read.

Comment: You're right about the code part being too verbose but that's not the point. I wrote another program with the bisection method and everything ran perfectly well. Entering the number "0.0001" didn't cause unexpected errors. I just can't understand what's causing this error in Newton's method.

Comment: @Diego All of this boils down to the simple fact that floating point is not exact.  I don't know how more simple to put it.  It doesn't matter if you're trying to implement Newton-Raphson, or simply summing up a few numbers -- round off error will result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, which was why the following piece of code does not work:

```
;i < N || f(xNext) > error;
```

It is simply because that, in a for loop condition, it is a *continuing* condition that is evaluated, and not a *stopping* condition. 
In the above piece of code, what you are telling the compiler is: *continue* the loop as long as either `i < N` is true or `f(xNext) > error` is true. Therefore,  when you input `x0 = 0.5`, `error = 0.0001` and `N = 100`, what the loop does is that it will not stop until both criteria are false, i.e. when i reaches **N** AND the tolerance in f(x) is smaller than **error**.

Now, the solution is simply to swap the `||` operator to `&&` operator. Like this:

```
i < N && f(xNext) > error;
```

but then, your `xNext` is not initialized. Because that your `xNext` and `xPrevious` are equal at the end of each loop, I would simply put `xPrevious` instead. In addition, as @Rathat has written, evaluating your tolerance in f(x) should take its absolute value, so:

```
i < N && abs(f(xPrevious)) > error;
```

Finally, you should output the number of iterations as `k + 1` since you started with `i = 0`.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the answers. I found out what's wrong besides the logic behind the `for` condition that @yuxiangDev explained very well. Despite @RatHat code being totally right the error was in the `math.h` library I was using. I tried with `<cmath>` and it worked really well! lol.